# textview not updating as expected

Tags: android

I have multiple `TextView` and `EditText` fields in two different activities. When I go to my Edit screen, I can input values and the corresponding `TextViews` are updated. The problem is that if I were to edit just one `TextView`, then the other `TextViews` go blank and only the ones I edited will show the correct info.  Any suggestions? Attached is a snippet of code. So basically, I only want the `TextView` info to change when the `EditText` field is changed and not when the `EditText` is just selected or scrolled through.

The `EditText` code:

```java
editTextName.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v1, int keyCode1, KeyEvent event1) {
        if ((event1.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode1 == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0).edit().putString("editTextName", editTextName.getText().toString()).commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

The corresponding `TextView`:

```java
String newName = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0).getString("editTextName", this.getString(R.string.name) );
textViewName.setText("Name: "+newName);
```

Comment: I suspect there's not enough information here to answer. You say you have multiple edittexts, what do the other ones look like? Can you put up the code for the other EditTexts/TextViews as well? When are you calling textViewName.setText, in onResume?

Comment: I think Tim's right that there's a missing piece here. What triggers the second block of code (the one that sets TextView's text) to run?

Comment: Very sorry i forgot to include. The second block of code(textview) is within an onResume of the main activity. Additionally, the other edittext and textviews are exactly the same just diff variables, eg name, address, occupation, etc. The problem is when i emulate and test the edit part, if i update every field at once it works perfectly. but if i were to edit say, just the second field then the other fields would display as blank in the updated textview.

Answer (score 0):

i just dont understand what u r trying to say but i think you want to know when the text  change in edittext for that there is a interfaces for this so u use this code :--

```
     editTextName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if ((event1.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
        getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0).edit().putString("editTextName", editTextName.getText().toString()).commit();
        return true;
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks for all the help, sorry i probably wasn't clear in describing it. But managed to get it fixed.